# How do I 301 redirect one domain to the other if the first has a folder path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, dns

I want to 301 redirect from: www.olddomain.com to the root of newdomain.com but I want it to work no matter what the folder path is on the old domain. eg: the following should all redirect to the root of newdomain.com

```
www.olddomain.com
olddomain.com
www.olddomain.com/folder/file.php
olddomain.com/folder/file.php
```

How can I do that with Mod Rewrite in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)old\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://new.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Where `old.example.com` is the old host name and `new.example.com` the new.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com/page.html");
exit();
?>
```

This should also work for you.