# Redirect all request from old domain to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am looking to migrate from old domain to new domain.

I have my old domain `olddomain.com` and new domain `newdomain.com` pointing to same ip address for now.

I have Apache server inplace to handle requests.

How do I `301 redirect` all my

```
olddomain.com/*
```

&

```
www.olddomain.com/*
```

to

```
newdomain.com/*
```

Can I get exact regex or configuration that I need to add in `htaccess`.

**My newdomain.com and olddomain.com both are being serverd by same apache from same IP so "/" redirect might lead to cycles? And so was looking for effecient way**

I tried

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [OR]
    #  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ http://comp16/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

And even tried adding in virtual host

```
RedirectMatch (.*)\.jpg$ http://comp17$1.jpg
```

But it does not redirect site when i hit localhost in browser to my computer name i.e comp16

Comment: Asking google would have been faster than adding a question here. ;-)

Comment: This will redirect all request of new and old domain to new domain, but I need only old domain urls to be redirected to new domain. Isn't this a different question than what is generally asked in google.

Comment: When running with `mod_rewrite` I would suggest you enable the `RewriteLog` to see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 18):

In the configuration (`VirtualHost`) for each of your `olddomain.com` host try this:

```
Redirect permanent / http://newdomain.com/
```

[Apache documentation for Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). This is the preferred way when everything should be redirected. If you must use `mode_rewrite/htaccess` there are plenty of questions around this on SO and one of them is:

[How do I 301 redirect one domain to the other if the first has a folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881640/how-do-i-301-redirect-one-domain-to-the-other-if-the-first-has-a-folder-path?rq=1)

**EDIT**
Recommendation from Apache regarding [simple redirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect):

```
mod_alias provides the Redirect and RedirectMatch directives, which provide a means to
redirect one URL to another. This kind of simple redirection of one URL, or a class of 
URLs, to somewhere else, should be accomplished using these directives rather than 
RewriteRule. RedirectMatch allows you to include a regular expression in your 
redirection criteria, providing many of the benefits of using RewriteRule.
```

Comment: Problem I feel here is both my new domain and old domain are looked over by same apache is such redirect fair enough?

Comment: Sure, performance wise it's better than fire up `mod_rewrite` and rewrite stuff. But I guess it's mostly up to what you feel comfortable to use. The recommendation for these kinds of things is however to use `Redirect` over `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend to use an If statement as you can use it also in a multisite server. Just type:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'old.example.com'">
    Redirect "/" "https://new.example.com/"
</If>
```

Answer (score -3):

Write the below code in to your .htaccess and it will redirect all your old domain request to new domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This will redirect all request of new and old domain to new domain, but I need only old domain urls to be redirected to new domain.