# Redirect domain to another domain and change url

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, http-status-code-301, domain-name

I have a website on

> mydomain.eu

and i want to redirect

> mydomain.com

and

> mydomain.org

to mydomain.eu. I want the url in the address bar to change to mydomain.eu.

Are there multiple ways to do this? 
For Example:

- apache virtualhost
- htaccess
- dns records/domain forwarding from registrar
- programmatically
- other

Can you give an example of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options you give are correct:

**apache virtualhost**

You can create a redirect here, when you do that you have to point the DNS records to the server where apache is running: 
an example can be found here: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

**htaccess**

Similar to the virtualhost solution except that he redirect is made in another file example: [Redirect all request from old domain to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357085/redirect-all-request-from-old-domain-to-new-domain)

**dns records/domain forwarding from registrar**

With a DNS record only you can't do a redirect it should always be used with a forwarding service or one of the other options given

**programmatically**

You can create a redirect in the code, you should point the DNS records to the server running the application and make your webserver listen to the domainnames. 
example in PHP: [How to redirect to another page using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871942/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-using-php)

Cheers!